# Did Julius Caesar say "If you can't defeat your enemy, have him as your friend"?

Tags: quotes, ancient-rome

In my country (Italy) there's a popular saying that goes "*Se non puoi sconfiggere il tuo nemico, fattelo amico*", translated to english as "*If you can't defeat your enemy, have him as your friend*".

This phrase is usually attributed to Julius Caesar, but I can't find a proper source confirming this.

I've tried searching the italian phrase, its english translation, and the (supposedly original) latin one: "*Si non potes inimicum tuum vincere, habeas eum amicum*".

The only results I get are from pages reporting the phrase as is, used as an introdution to some argument, and maybe adding "*attributed to Caesar*".

So did Julius Caesar really say "*If you cannot defeat your enemy, have him as your friend*" and if so is there any direct source I can cite for this?

Or is it maybe an adaptation of the english proverb "*if you can't beat them, join them*"? And if so what's its origin?

Comment: To me this seems to be related in meaning to the saying "keep your friends close and your enemies closer", maning keep your enemies close y so you can keep track of what they are up to.

Comment: @M.A.Golding It's not quite the same thing, it's much closer in spirit to "If you can't beat them, join them" as said in the OP. The idea is that having a permanent conflict with someone you can't defeat is pointlessly self-destructive, so you are better served in finding common ground, even if it costs you.